# How do I insert two related records into two different tables with a single query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with a relation by `id`. And I want to insert two related records. The problem is that `id` is not known until I make the first insert. Is there a way to write a kind of embedded query that makes both inserts correctly? I would like to have one exact query and to avoid variables, if it is possible. What I tried is:

```
insert into "b" ("value", "b_id")
  select 'val2', (select insert into "a" ("value") values ('val1') returning id);
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to do that, `INSERT` statements cannot be arbitrarily nested (unlike `SELECT`):

```
WITH a_results AS (
  INSERT INTO a (value)
  VALUES ('val1')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO b (value, b_id)
SELECT 'val2', id
FROM a_results;
```